# Objects in outliner out of order when importing?

Tags: outliner

Why does blender import files into the outliner in the following pattern: object1, object11, object2, object3, ...

Instead of object1, object2, object3, ... object10, object11?

Objects seem to be out of order when they are imported in the outliner. Is there any way to fix the order to follow the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** They are not out of order/it is not supported in Blender.

**Long answer**: they *are* sorted, just not in the way you would expect.

They are sorted in purely alphabetical order, from a cold computer perspective `1`comes before `2` so `Object11` alphabetically speaking comes before `Object2`

What you are expecting is [Natural Sort Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order), which is not widely supported in software, and must be explicitly coded to do so, which is apparently not the case in Blender Outliner.

That is why using leading zeros in your digital names (files, objects, data values, etc.) like `Object.001` is always a good idea.

**How to work around it :**
Make sure in the outliner *View Menu > Sort Alphabetically* is ticked.

If you really want them to be sorted use a third party addon like [Name Panel](http://Name%20Panel) to manually rename the objects and add leading zeros.